# How to move CSS navbar elements to the right?

Tags: css, css-float, navbar

For an online course I was taking I created a web app through heroku

Here is the site: http://sportmem.herokuapp.com/#

In the top I have a navigation bar with elements for home, about, faq, contact, login and register

I would like to move the login and register elements to the right of the navigation bar so the login drop-down menu looks nicer

here is the code I tried

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class = "navbar-inner">
      <div class = "container">
        <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-navbar" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".nav-collapse">
          <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
          <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
          <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class = "brand" href = "#"><span class = "SportMem-sport">Sport</span><span class = "SportMem-mem">Mem</span></a>
        <div class = "nav-collapse collapse">
          <ul class = "nav">
            <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href = "/faq">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href = "/contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class = "login">
          <a id = "login-start" href = "#">
         Login<span></span>
          </a>
          <div id = "login-form">
        <form>
          <fieldset id = "inputs">
            <input id = "username" type = "email" name = "Email" placeholder = "Email Address" required>
            <input id = "password" type = "password" name = "Password" placeholder = "Password" required>
                  </fieldset>
          <fieldset id = "actions">
            <input type = "submit" id = "submit" value = "Log-in">
            <label><input type = "checkbox" checked = "checked"> Keep me logged-on</label>
                  </fieldset>
                </form>
              </div>
        </li>
        <li class = "register.html"><a href = "#register">Register</a></li>
          </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

i tried floating the elements to the right among others but nothing I've tried worked

Could someone please find me a solution?

Help is greatly appreciated

Edit: Here is the entire CSS code in case you're wondering

```
<style type = "text/css">
      @media (min-width: 980px) {
        body {
          padding-top: 60px;
        }
        .linediv-l {
          border-right: 3px #DAA520 solid;
        }
        .linediv-r {
          border-left: 3px #DAA520 solid;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 480px) {
        .copy {
          padding: 2.5% 10%;
        }
        .linediv-l {
          border-bottom: 3px #DAA520 solid;
        }
        .linediv-r {
          border-top: 3px #DAA520 solid;
        }
      } 

      a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: gold;
      }

      a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }

      a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }

     .navbar {
        position: fixed;
      }

      #login-form {
        display:none;
        position: absolute;
      }

      ul > li {
        display: inline;
        color: white;
      }

      body {
        background-color: #A52A2A;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      }

      .heading, .subheading {
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .brand {
        display: inline;
      }

      .SportMem-sport {
        color:#DAA520;
      }

      .SportMem-mem {
        color: #32CD32;
      }

      .subheading {
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 12px;
      }

      p.lead {
        padding-top: 1.5%;
        line-height: 30px;
      }

      p {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 24px;
      }

      .pitch {
        padding: 2.5% 0%;
      }

      .order {
        padding: 2% 0%;
      }

      .actions {
        background-color: #343434;
        padding: 3% 0%;
        border: 5px solid #00008B;
      }

      .actions:hover {
        border: 5px solid #4B0082;
      }

      img {
        border: 5px solid #006400;
      }

      img:hover {
        border: 5px solid #DAA520;
      }

      .video, .thermometer, .order, .social, .statistics {
        text-align: center;
      }

      .statistics h3, .statistics p {
        color: white;
      }

      .copy {
        padding-top: 2.5%;
        padding-bottom: 2.5%;
        text-align: justify;
      } 

      .asset {
        padding: 2.5% 0%;
      }

      h3 {
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFD700;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px #00008B;
      }

      h3:hover {
        color: #20B2AA;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px #F8F8FF;
      }

      .footer li {
        color: #cccccc;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline;
      }

      div.addthis_toolbox {
        width:180px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
```

there is no float:left found

I don't know how that guy figured it out

Comment: create demo on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 4):

**This is the snapshot after making changes**:
[image: snapshot of changed website code]

Remove `float:left;`  from

```
 <ul class="nav">
```

and add `float:right;` in login and register

```
<li class="login" style="float:right;">
<li class="register.html" style="float:right;">
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i have tried your changes and all that changed was moving login to the right of register. There is still no space between contact and register.

Comment: modify <ul class="nav"> to <ul class="nav" style="float: none!Important;"> this will fix the problem..

Answer (score 1):

In the context of Bootstrap, all previous answers are wrong. There is specifically `navbar-left` and `navbar-right` to handle just this situation. You should not be trying to float elements left and right on your own, you should be using the provided classes.

The reason you are seeing no space between the elements is that when you apply float to multiple items and they end up next to each other, any margins are ignored when they are floated. The only way to maintain those margins is to put the items in a containing div and float that div, which is why the Bootstrap framework provided `navbar-left` and `navbar-right`.

As you also should have noticed, when floating right on each individual item instead of a containing div, is that you have to define the element in your markup as the first element if you want it to be the far right element; which is obviously unintuitive and should be avoided since someone coming behind you may not understand what is happening.

I know this is 3 years late, but I felt the proper instructions needed to be pointed out. Bootstrap's website has examples of how to structure the navbar:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shift items to the right, a simple text align should work:
`<li class = "login" style="text-align: right;">`
Or, if you want to use CSS & HTML:
**HTML:** `<li class = "login">`
**CSS:**

```
.login {
text-align: right;
}
```